# Load jQuery, wait

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, wait

I need to dynamically load jQuery and jQuery UI from a javascript, then check if it has loaded and do something afterwards.

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file

  var fileref=document.createElement('script');
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link");
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}


loadjscssfile("http://localhost/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js", "js");
loadjscssfile("http://localhost/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js", "js");
```

I have done some research and found that I need to either use a callback or a settimeout. Trouble is I'm really new in javascript and it's really giving me a hard time. Can anyone set me in the right direction please?

Comment: Dynamically loading javascript files is a reasonably advanced subject for somebody who's new to javascript. Why are you loading these scripts dynamically?

Comment: why don't you load them the normal way (i.e. by using the plain `<script>` or `<link>` tag?

Comment: because this javascript file gets called from within a bookmarklet, it has to dynamically create a div inside a site.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've never had to do this myself, but presumably you could just use a repeating timeout to check for presence of the needed objects:

```
function jqueryLoaded() {
    //do stuff
}

function checkJquery() {
    if (window.jQuery && jQuery.ui) {
        jqueryLoaded();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(checkJquery, 100);
    }
}

checkJquery();
```

Comment: this was exactly what i'm looking for. Trouble is, for some reason it doesn't loop. I'm checking it via firebug and it definetly adds everything I need. If I click the bookmarklet again, it works. My conclusion is that it doesn't loop.

function checkJquery() {
    if (jQuery().dialog) {
        jqueryLoaded();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout("100", checkJquery);
    }
}

checkJquery();

Comment: I noticed mine wasn't looping either. Then I realized I forgot to initiate the script by calling checkJquery(); first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the [window.onload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) function should trigger when all scripts are loaded. And you don't need to bind stuff to the '`ready`' event in jQuery.

```
loadjscssfile("http://localhost/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js", "js");
loadjscssfile("http://localhost/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js", "js");

window.onload = function() {
    if(window.jQuery && jQuery.ui) {
        alert('loaded');
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not work at all. The first version was closer to working. Thanks for the help though!