# How to stop jQuery functions running, until the jQuery library has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I saw someone asking this question, it was marked as answered - but I don't believe it answers my further question.

I am trying to embed a calendar into my customers pages - the JS, CSS and jQuery are held on my server, so to allow my customers to just have to add one line of code, the link I give them, links to a JS file, which then dynamically loads the other files required, then adds a textbox, dropdown and button to the BOM, using document.write.

However, to add the jQuery calendar to the textbox, I have to be sure jQuery has loaded.  If it hasn't, by the time the page script hits the $( to check for jQuery, if it hasn't loaded, all of the jQuery is ignored.  How can I get the script to stop and wait (without having the customer having to press a button)?

So I give my customers this one line:

```
<script src="http://www.myserver.com/testjs/js/mt.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The mt.js file contains:

```
//JS to load files
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype) {
if (filetype == "js") { //if filename is a external JavaScript file
    var fileref = document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
}
else if (filetype == "css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
    var fileref = document.createElement("link")
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
    fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
}
if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("http://www.myserver.com/testjs/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css", "css");
loadjscssfile("http://www.myserver.com/testjs/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js", "js");
loadjscssfile("http://www.myserver.com/testjs/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js", "js");

//write GUI to DOM
document.write("<input id=\"calendar\" type=\"text\" />");
document.write("<input id=\"btnCheck\" type=\"button\" value=\"Check\" />");
document.write("<br /><div id=\"result\" />");

//Jquery to add calendar to textbox added above
$(function () {
$("#calendar").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
....
....
});
```

So if the jQuery/UI/CSS hasn't loaded, the script will get here, without having added the jQuery calendar to the textbox.

Can anyone advise how to overcome this please?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: I think this question gives you your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011938/load-jquery-wait

Answer (score 0):

I think your way won't work. Because:

You use the menthod `.appendChild()`. That means the new HTML tags will be appended at the end of your `<head>` element. Appending a child does not mean that the browser will execute these automaticaly.
Based on this fact you have to seperate your standard js code and the JQuery code.
If you want to test -if jquery is loaded- read [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html). After a successful test, you can run your datepicker code or put your code into it (is a better way).
.

Comment: Hi - do you mean if I take my jquery code to "make" the calendar, and load that as a separate js (at the end of my current file loads), it should run after the other scripts are loaded?

loadjscssfile("http://www.myserver.com/testjs/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css", "css"); 
loadjscssfile("http://www.myserver.com/testjs/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js", "js"); 
loadjscssfile("http://www.myserver.com/testjs/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js", "js"); 
loadjscssfile("http://www.myserver.com/testjs/js/myjquerycodetorunhere.js", "js"); 
 
Thanks again, Mark

Comment: No, I meant you have to make sure that your source code for calendar will be executed after the script tag for jquery files has been executed (e.g. at the begin of your body tag or wrapping it into an event -for example 'onLoad')

Comment: Hi - thanks - I won't have control over the onLoad though, as this will be embedded into customers existing pages.  If I simply give my customers 4 lines of code, to embed, <script src="http://www.myserver.com/testjs/js/mt.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script> etc - rather than the 1 I had hoped to give - does loading the scripts in this way, as opposed to .appendChild, have then load/run in order?  So if my call to create the jquery calendar is done within my final <script> file, would that avoid this problem?  Thank you again.  Mark

Comment: You can't keep the JQuery code in the head tag (even in a
seperate script tag). At the moment you read the head tag, the other tags after this line do not exists yet. In my eyes, the only one option you will have is to move the Jquery code within the body tag.

Comment: Thank you - is that as simple as changing the loadjscssfil function to: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(fileref)

Comment: I think you din't understand me. You can move the javascript files whereever you want, it won't change your problem. The basic problem is, you have to execute the three script tags first, before you can use yor jquery code. What is so hard to understand? Maybe the use of AJAX will solve the problem. Why? Well, you can try to store the content of all files in a variable. Using the eval() -method and then execute the last code. Except sending more than one file, this is the only option that you have got.