# Wait for jQuery to load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if jQuery is loaded. If not, load it, then proceed to load external javascript files. The issue I'm having is one of the external files expects to have jQuery already loaded, so I get a 'jQuery not defined" error. Is there a way I can load jQuery using JavaScript, and as soon as it's done then continue?

```
if(!window.jQuery){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

//load these scripts after jquery has been loaded

<script src="/some/other/js/file/that/requires/jquery"></script>
<script src="/some/other/js/file/that/requires/jquery"></script>
```

What I'd like to do is wait for this to completely load before continuing. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011938/load-jquery-wait) but I got errors about exceeding call stack

Comment: Did you try just adding the script tags in the usual order, and relying on Google not failing ?

Comment: or downloading jQuery and loading it from your own js directory?

Comment: It pains me to say this, but this is an instance in which I'd recommend using `document.write()` to add the `<script>` tag. That way you've insured that it'll load just like any other `<script>` tag (i.e., synchronously). Note that usual practice is to hard-code the CDN `<script>` tag, and then add your local copy if that fails. It doesn't make a lot of sense to plan for your own server failing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the technique tried and tested by [HTML5Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html) instead:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Note that `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com` only works on an actual `http:` or `https:` server; if you're testing on a local filesystem, write `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com` instead.

Comment: I'm assuming the /js/vendor/jquery....is a path from my server or did you accidentally leave out the rest?

Comment: That's where HTML5Boilerplate puts the jQuery file. You should, of course, change it to whatever's appropriate.

Comment: @Blazmonger sorry, I meant should I link a google hosted one or from my own server? Just wondering if it makes a big difference. Speed isn't a hugely over the top factor for this instance, I just want to make sure jQuery is loaded. I didn't know if the source was important.

Comment: The first line of code calls for Google's CDN version of jQuery; the second line calls your local version of jQuery if and only if Google's didn't work.